# Search bar disappears when interactive pop gesture is happening

Tags: swift, ios11, uisearchcontroller, interactivepopgesture

I'm adding search controller like this:

```
        viewController.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        viewController.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        viewController.definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        searchBarContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchBarContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
```

and when try to swipe right to pop current viewController (interactive pop gesture activates here) but stay on the same controller the search bar just disappears.

```
viewController.navigationItem.searchController
```

holds added search controller but it's not visible.

Comment: Same issue. Did you find a fix ?

Comment: No. Will update in case some news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this code to whatever class `viewController` is an instance of:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

That did the trick for me.